# Is it illegal to state facts I got from othere sources and get paid for it?

Tags: copyright

I'm making a video project based off the beta of a certain video game for You Tube. I got some history from a website and I want to get paid for my video with ads. Am I allowed to do this if I got my info from another site, even if I credit them?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what exactly you are doing. First, check if you are under any legal restrictions. If you received a beta version of a video game, it is quite possible that there are restrictions what you can do with it. If you got the information indirectly, and *your* source wasn't allowed to publish what they published, then this is legally dubious. Legally dubious means you can get sued which might be expensive, no matter whether you are right or wrong, if what you are doing annoys the makers of the video game enough.

Using images from the video game may quite likely be copyright infringement. You would have an excuse if you do something like writing a review, or creating a parody. If you use copyrighted images to make money, you most likely have no excuse.

On the other hand, if you create something yourself that is *inspired* by that video game and doesn't actually copy anything, you should be fine. Important is always: You will get sued if you annoy people enough to sue you. (If you have tons of money, you can get sued because people want your money. A video game company will not sue you for that reason unless you are Bill Gates posting anonymously here)